# NSFetchedResultsController crash when using CONTAINS in predicate

Tags: core-data, ios6, nspredicate

Entity contains `CLPlacemark` property. 
I want to check if `city` string matches to locality property of placemark.

Crash happens on `performFetch` when I use `CONTAINS` in predicate.

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"placemark.locality CONTAINS[cd] %@", city];
[_fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The placemark that is saved in Core Data cannot be a `CLPlacemark` because Core Data does not support that type.

So, is the `placemark` in your predicate a NSManagedObject with an attribute `locality` of type NSString?  If it isn't, the crash is not due to the CONTAINS but to the predicate trying to access an attribute `placemark.locality` which does not exist.

Thus, if your placemark is saved in Core Data as a binary data type, you cannot access its components and you could not write a predicate referring to its locality property.

Comment: placemark is transformable type, and in Entity class it's set to CLPlacemark. OK, thanks, I think I'll try to create getter method for locality in class to solve that

Comment: If it's a transformable type, you cannot access `locality` in a predicate.  You have to make a `Placemark` Entity.  To the new Placemark Entity, you would add any attributes (such as `locality`) of `CLPlacemark` that you are interested in & want to save to Core Data.  Thus, you won't have the full ClPlacemark in Core Data, but you _will_ be able to access its components, or at least the once for which you created attributes.

Comment: I hope this is helpful and that it is clear.  A transformable attribute is saved in Core Data as NSData.  So, a fetch request will only see a blob of NSData, and that NSData will not be transformed back into a CLPlacemark until after it has been retrieved from Core Data. In other words, the fetch request will not be able to see into the components of the CLPlacemark because it has been converted into NSData to be stored in Core Data. And, since the predicate tries to access `locality`, and `locality` does not exist in Core Data, it crashes.

Comment: Still crashing even when I created getter method in class...
I also can't understand why crash happens if I use:

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        Place *place = (Place *)evaluatedObject;
        return [place.placemark.locality isEqualToString:_city];
    }];

Comment: Creating a getter does NOT work.  To write the predicate as you have it, Placemark MUST be an Entity and locality MUST be a Core Data attribute.  Take a look at your Core Data model.  If you do not see `locality` in the object graph, you CANNOT write a fetch predicate referring to `locality`.  _The simplest way to do it is to look at the Core Data model (the .xcdatamodeld file) before writing any fetch predicate._  If it's not in the model you CANNOT write it in a predicate.

Comment: As to predicateWithBlock, Core Data does not support predicateWithBlock for SQL stores.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20441/discussion-between-salo-dm-and-flink)